# Unable to change thread_stack size MySQL Windows

Tags: mysql

I got the following error on MySQL 8.0 **Windows** on large recursive procedure:

```
Error Code: 1436. Thread stack overrun:  127944 bytes used of a 286720 byte stack, and 160000 bytes needed.
Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

After doing hours of research on how to increase stack size.
Here are my findings:

1. there is no `.cnf` file anywhere;
2. there is a single `my.ini` file in the hidden `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\` but not in the `Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\`;
3. there is no `thread_stack` value in that `.ini` file;
4. there is no data folder in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\` but there is a data folder in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\`.
5. To execute `mysqld` commands in command prompt I had to create a blank `data` folder in the Program Files subfolder:
   [image]
6. On executing the above command, there are two findings:

[image]

[image]

So, here's is what I did to increase it 4x:

1. I added a `thread_stack=1120K` line under `[mysqld]` in the `my.ini` file using notepad as administrator. (286720*4/1024 = 1120).
2. (on suggestion of a user but did nothing) added semicolons(initially not present) around the url after `datadir` in the same `my.ini`.

Now after I again ran the `verbose --help` command it still showed me the same stack size

So, I copied the 'my.ini' file from ProgramData into the `C:\Windows\` folder as the mysqld statement searches that directory for config files. (as mentioned in the image)

Now when I ran the command again:

[image]

And here the size has increased. But, the main thing is after I use `mysql -u root -p`, connect with the server and use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%thread_stack%';`

[image]

Here there is no change in the size.

Here I am stuck, how to do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Where, **exactly** did you change the variable in my.ini? Under what section? Under [mysqld] or somewhere else?

Comment: @Vérace under [mysqld], although before that there were couple of statements under [client]

Comment: OK - belt and braces time. Put your new desired value **everywhere** - under [client], [mysql] **and** [mysqld], reboot and see what happens!

Comment: @Vérace didn't work, `mysql -u root -p` refused to run quoting the added line. I guess it has to be only under `mysqld` because I solved the same problem in `ubuntu` in `my.cnf` file and there I only put it under `mysqld`

Comment: Was the change to my.ini in the `[mysqld]` section?  Did you restart mysqld after that?  Anyway, it is very dangerous to change the stack size.

Comment: @RickJames Yes the problem was solved in ubuntu by putting only under `[mysqld]` (even which I had to manually type because the `my.cnf`) was empty. But in Windows there was a change in `mysqld --versbose --help` but not in the server config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

Before you start changing the my.ini file make sure you have a copy of a working my.ini file as a Backup.

The problem lies with the text editing.  If you open my.ini in Notepad it will save the file as my.ini.txt even though the .txt extension might not show up.  As a result MySQL does not recognize the file as a configuration file and does not load it on startup.

So, add the following single line: thread_stack=512K (or your preferred size) under the [mysqld] section of the my.ini file.  Don't include -- before thread_stack.

Then save the file as my.ini and make sure "All Files (*.*)" is displayed in the Save dialogue.  This should prevent it from being saved as a .txt file and will be recognized by Windows as a configuration file.

Comment: thanks, your deduction was correct

Comment: There also may be an issue of the way Windows 10 deals with files versus Windows 7., when using MySQL 8.0.  The fix above does not work on my Windows 7 machine but it does on the Windows 10 machine.  Probably related to Path but I have not had time to track that down.